# How should I get an OAuth2.0 Access token in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0

I am trying to make an Unsplash photo client, which requires me to use the website's API. As per the documentation, in order to have access to photo related info( like pageURls, imagesURLs etc ) oAuth2.0 is required. It states I must do the following things :

1. Direct the user to https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize with some query parameters.
2. If the user accepts the request, the user will be redirected to the                                            `redirect_ui`(one of the parameters)  , with the authorization code in the code query parameter
3. Make a POST request to https://unsplash.com/oauth/token with some parameters.

This is how I tried to implement this in code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    authenticator()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func authenticator(){

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize", parameters: [
    "client_id": "2902affb00634248f77b3c5c7a4ba4232fa36e3cbaad826b223a27f3df57e642"
    , "redirect_uri": "Sample//:" ,
      "response_type" : "code" ,
      "scope":"" ]).responseJSON{ response in
print("original URL request : \(response.request) ")
print("URL response : \(response.response) ")
    }


    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize", parameters: [
        "client_id"    : "2902affb00634248f77b3c5c7a4ba4232fa36e3cbaad826b223a27f3df57e642",
        "client_secret":"6e85c0e5bcda025f0553e1343dcbdd8a892b0db1cc3a653055d84ce44c217bb9",
        "redirect_uri" : "Sample//:" ,
        "code" : "c15781809f4ee781e6019b958a2702be0dab61e89df96863693dbd7d48bacd53" ,
        "grant_type":"authorization_code" ])
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what I get :

```
  Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f9cf959f700> { URL:        https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize })
  Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9cf941f920> { URL: https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize } { status code: 422, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 8440;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Thu, 18 Aug 2016 15:24:30 GMT";
Server = Cowboy;
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000";
Via = "1.1 vegur, 1.1 varnish";
"X-Cache" = MISS;
"X-Cache-Hits" = 0;
"X-Ratelimit-Limit" = 100;
"X-Ratelimit-Remaining" = 94;
"X-Request-Id" = "f00ae2f9-6369-4526-9b28-283c294e2a30";
"X-Runtime" = "0.012134";
"X-Served-By" = "cache-sin6920-SIN";
"X-Timer" = "S1471533870.429494,VS0,VE550";
 } })
   Optional(<3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c3e0a 3c68746d 6c3e0a3c 68656164 3e0a2020 ....2e 636f6d2f 616e616c 79746963 732e6a73 272c2767 6127293b 0a0a2020 20206761 28276372 65617465 272c2027 55412d33 36303439 3637302d 34272c20 27617574 6f27293b 0a202020 20676128 2773656e 64272c20 27706167 65766965 7727293b 0a202020 20676128 2773656e 64272c20 27657665 6e74272c 20276163 74696f6e 272c2027 34323227 293b0a20 203c2f73 63726970 743e0a0a 3c2f626f 64793e0a 3c2f6874 6d6c3e0a>)
   FAILURE
```

How shall I resolve this error?

Comment: I am still trying to figure this out. No success yet.

Answer (score 4):

Did you figure this out ? If not I will give you a hint. Follow my step you will get success with Access-Token return from Unsplash.

First, we will find-out how to use this request `https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize`. With this request you need use UIWebView because this will return you a HTML page.

Try this `https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=Your_App_ID&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=public+read_user+write_user+read_photos+write_photos+write_likes+read_collections+write_collections` with UIWebView.

After this request by using UIWebView you will get a code returned like this `https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize/f2ad36deb30b37a2614898e366b84e7c0f68fccd0358565cfbdc2637e*****`

The code after /authorize/ is the code you need to fill your `code` parameter with request `https://unsplash.com/oauth/token` - Now you can use Alamofire to get your Token.

Just give questions if you still having problems

Comment: I abandoned the Unsplash API and started working with the pixabay API , because I was wasting a lot of time on the problem. Thanks for you answer though. Once I am through with other problems I will implement your solution.